# focus not working for input and !important does not do anything

Tags: css

I can't get the input:focus to work. I have tried to override with the !important keyword but it still fails. When on focus, it's a solid black and not the desired color of #dd3333.

```
input {
width: 400px;
height: 35px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 10px 10px;
font-size: 16px;
}

input:focus {
    border: 1px solid #dd3333; 
}
```

I have uploaded the source code for review on git. You can access via the following link: https://github.com/SophalLee/resume.innovisage.com. The contact.html page is the one I am having issues with.

Comment: Can you add a minimal reproducable example?

Comment: I've added the source code to git. You can access it via https://github.com/SophalLee/resume.innovisage.com. I'm having issues with contact.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove default `outline` style first

```
input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #dd3333;
}
```